# How to replace type: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame with type: modin.pandas.dataframe.DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, ray, modin

I try to replace pandas with modin pandas in the code:

```
if not isinstance(X, pd.DataFrame):
    raise TypeError(
        "X is not a pandas dataframe. The dataset should be a pandas dataframe.")
```

but the error is:

```
DataFrame Expected type <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>, found <class 'modin.pandas.dataframe.DataFrame'> instead
```

How should I change code to solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by devin-petersohn on Github related to this issue you can simply import modin.pandas as such:

```py
import modin.pandas as m_pd

if not isinstance(X, m_pd.DataFrame):
    raise TypeError(
        "X is not a pandas dataframe. The dataset should be a pandas dataframe.")
```

an alternative could be to call `_to_pandas()` function, but then you could run into error handling loop.

Source:

https://github.com/modin-project/modin/issues/896